# how to insert an array of values into a database using C# winForms

Tags: c#, winforms, postgresql

I am creating a application that tracks time. A user inputs his or her user ID and clicks clock in. The application allows for multiple users to be logged in at the same time. I want to clock all users out when they exit the application and insert user ID, username and Time Out for each user that is clocked in into my database. Clocking all users out when the application is close will hopefully provide better time reporting if a user forgets to clock out. My question is how would this be accomplished, would I use arrays or is using a list better for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Where does the array come in? I don't see any need for an array or list.

Comment: I am assuming array because there will multiple users checked in, I want to be able to insert time stamps and IDs for all users checked in on application exit. What would be a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you structure you store data for each user is up to you. One acceptable method would be to use a `List` that contains an entry for each user. You could also use a `Dictionary` with the user ID as the key for each entry. I would stay away from arrays here because they are best if you have a fixed number of entries, which you clearly don't.

To insert the values into the database, simply use a `foreach` loop to iterate over each item in the list and insert it (unless you are using EntityFramework or something similar; then everything is different).